Which Java 11+ HttpClient BodyHandler return chunks as they arrive?
I want to get data from a server that sends chunked data, in my case line by line.
I checked this answer suggesting a custom BodySubscriber, as well as this one resorting to an InputStream.
My current code looks like this:
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class HttpClientTest {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/chunked";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting HttpClientTest");
        HttpClientTest httpTest = new HttpClientTest();
        httpTest.run();
    }

    Consumer<String> dataSink = new Consumer<String>() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
            // Some logic here for line processing - omitted for brevity
            System.out.println(t);
            count++;
            System.out.println("Count: " + count);
        }
    };

   void run() throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(BASE_URL)).GET().build();

        HttpResponse<Stream<String>> response =
                client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines());

        response.body().forEach(dataSink);
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}

My question: Will this process chunks as they arrive?
The BodyHandler Javadoc doesn't mention anything about chunked. or do I need a different (potentially custom (?)) BodyHandler?

Your first sentence confuses me.  Do you want to read the response line by line, or do you want to read the exact HTTP chunks?  If you want to read it line by line, your code looks correct.

@VGR  Thx for chipping in The chunks arrive line by line, so one line is one chunk. I want to process them when they arrive, not wait until after the request has completed

I am not seeing that behavior.  For me, it starts printing lines as soon as they're received.

Data is delivered to the BodyHandler/BodySubscriber as it arrives. If your server sends data line by line and you want to process it line by line then yes ofLines() is probably the best fit.

Note that if the stream is not walked to exhaustion (e.g. dataSink throws in the middle of the stream) - then the underlying HTTP connection/stream/request might be left pending, which will prevent from closing/garbage collecting the HttpClient.
To avoid this kind of issues I would recommend using try-with-resource on the returned stream - as in:
try (var st = response.body()) { st.forEach(dataSink); }
